# VBA Excel preserve Circle invalid data after saving and opening

Tags: excel, vba

The procedure of having Data Validation is done. All i want to do is Circle invalid data and that works fine as well. The issue is that when i save the workbook (or macro saves it) the circles disappear. How to preserve them?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, the circle invalid data will disappear after saving workbook. The workaround is to use Conditional formatting which is easy to record and adjust to my needs.